# Number System Conversion

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

0 down vote favorite

I have a paradox: EIGHTY is a six digit number with no repeating digits and no zeros. When divided by 19, 17, 13, 11, or H, the remainders are, respectively, 17, 13, 11, 7 and G.

TWENtY is (another) six digit number with no repeating digits and no zeros (and uses a different key to EIGHTY above). When divided by T, perfect square WE or perfect cube NtY, the remainder is zero.

Find EIGHTY TWENtY

My interpretation is: The question requires a fractional base system converion e.g. 20 converted to base 2 is and 0010100 and 20 converted to base 1.6 is approximately 1001001.2589 which is a six digit number but both have repeating digits and zeros.

Comment: I am pretty sure that aplhabets are digits in the system too, so EIGHTY has nothing to do with $80$. So EIGHTY has digits E,I,G,H,T and Y - thus six digits, no repeating digits, right?

Comment: you cannot give a solution ad neglect the second most important part - i.e. When divided by 19, 17, 13, 11, or H, the remainders are, respectively, 17, 13, 11, 7 and G.

Comment: Sorry that I did not make that clear - I was merely making a comment about the interpreation of the question, not claiming to have a solution.

Comment: I don't know why you think the question requires a fractional base system. Why can't it be about base 10?

Comment: As you commented below, this question was crossposted to [Puzzling.SE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11218/number-systems-or-analytical-thinking), where it received a very thorough answer. I don't think it's useful to leave it posted here.

Answer (score 2):

I could find TWENtY = **349125**.
Since WE is perfect square, it belongs to set: {25,36,49,49,64,81}
and NtY is perfect cube, it belongs to set: {125,216,343,512,729}.
Now, using the given information of no repeating digits, no zeros and the remainder, we can make combinations of WE and NtY to find TWENtY.
I could not find EIGHTY, but I have a question here. Are the digits 'T','E','Y' in TWENtY the same as that in EIGHTY ?

Comment: No, they are not the same. http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11218/number-systems-or-analytical-thinking/11220?noredirect=1#comment34321_11220

Comment: Ok, now I saw the solution to the question.